# How do I set state of activeID to be the specific feature.id of a selected icon on MapBox in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop, mapbox

Moving on from the question stated on [How do you center the map on a clicked symbol using MapBox and React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167738/how-do-you-center-the-map-on-a-clicked-symbol-using-mapbox-and-react-native/55245472#55245472), I've been trying to setState of my activeID (the id of my selected feature) from my geoJson. Aka, when I select an Icon with a a specific feature.id, how do I set state to that icon's feature.id. In my code below, activeID is undefined. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE: I tried to console.log feature.id (see in code below) and I get undefined. I am for some reason not able to reach it.

Sample feature:

{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Hotel"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.584664,
          55.680532
        ]
      }
    }

---

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    activeIndex: 0,
    activeID: -1,

    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
    this.onActiveIndexChange = this.onActiveIndexChange.bind(this);

async onPress(pressFeature) {
    const { screenPointX, screenPointY } = pressFeature.properties;

    const hitFeatureCollection = await this.map.queryRenderedFeaturesAtPoint(
            [screenPointX, screenPointY],
            null,
            ['singleIcon']
     );

    let feature = null;
    let currentFeature = null;
    if (hitFeatureCollection.features.length > 0) {
        feature = hitFeatureCollection.features[0];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.featureCollection.features.length; i++) {
            currentFeature = this.props.featureCollection.features[i];
            console.log(feature.id);

            if (feature.id === currentFeature.id) {
                this.setState({
                    activeIndex: i,
                    isChangeFromPress: true,
                    destination: feature.geometry.coordinates
                });
            break;
        }
    }
}

onActiveIndexChange(index) {
    const feature = this.props.featureCollection.features[index];

        if (!feature) {
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            activeIndex: index,
            activeID: feature.id,
            isChangeFromPress: false,
            destination: feature.geometry.coordinates
        });
}
```

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(feature)`

Comment: type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: Array(2)}
properties: {placeID: 3, icon: "cafe", name: "Cafe Victor"}
type: "Feature"
______
it seems the id disappears after I call queryRenderedFeaturesAtPoint

Comment: https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/issues/652 This might have something to do with it. Try setting the id as a property and call it from `feature.properties.id` instead.

Comment: that was my short-term fix, and it works, but it feels like it contradicts the point of feature.id? as now there is an id twice... thoughts?

Comment: No dice if it's a bug or there isn't support for it. Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/API.md#feature) it seems that `id` isn't a property that is listed for features but is a property for layers and source. Although you would assume that ID should be an available property for mostly any object, it might not be here.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

Short terms solution is adding an id to the feature.properties, so the new geoJson looks like this:

{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "id": 1, "type": "Feature", "properties": { "placeID": 1, "name": "Hotel" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.584664, 55.680532 ] } }

Please let me know if you have a better solution!